# What happens to the files in directories mounted by initrd , when initrd unmounts

Tags: linux-kernel, initrd

While the linux boots up, `initrd` is mounted with basic support files and kernel modules, which are needed to help further boot procedure. Later the `rootfs` is mounted and `initrd` is unmounted from the Linux OS. My question is if the `initrd` is unmounted how can a user still see the files mounted by `initrd` ?

Ex: some files in `/etc`, `/lib` etc..

Comment: Opposite question: why do you think the user would _not_ be able to see those mounts? They're only mounted _by_ the initrd – they don't come _from_ the initrd.

Comment: Let me elaborate my question. AFAIK, initrd is a disk image when uncompressed will contain many directories like /etc, /lib, /bin, /usr, .. . When the initrd is mounted in the boot process to the ram, these directories and its contents will be present in the system. During the later stage of boot process, initrd will be unmounted and rootfs will be mounted. My question is when the initrd is unmounted, why the directories  /etc, /lib, /bin, /usr,.. and their contents are still present?

Comment: It depends on implementation, but at least for [busybox-based initramfs using switch_root](https://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/util-linux/switch_root.c?h=1_36_0), it deletes all initramfs files before switching to the real root filesystem and init system (rm -rf, mount --move, chroot, exec init). You can read the source code, it has a very long comment. There are other implementations - once the kernel unpacks initramfs and execs /init for you, it no longer cares what happens afterward

Answer (score 7):

> Later the rootfs is mounted and initrd is unmounted from the Linux OS

It is not exactly "unmounted"; most Linux distributions haven't used a mountable initrd for *years.* Instead, they use an "initramfs" which is an archive that gets *extracted* into a RAM filesystem (tmpfs) that's initially mounted at "/". Even though it is still specified using the `initrd=` option, it behaves completely differently from the original initrd mechanism.

> My question is when the initrd is unmounted, why the directories /etc, /lib, /bin, /usr,.. and their contents are still present?

Because they are not actually "/etc" or "/lib" from the initramfs point of view. The initramfs **doesn't mount "/" directly** – the initramfs *itself* is "/" – instead it mounts the real root filesystem at something like "/mnt" or "/newroot", so those directories **start off as "/newroot/lib" and such.**

One of the final steps done by the initramfs is to either "pivot_root()" or "mount(MS_MOVE)", an operation that **makes "/newroot" become the new "/"**, essentially exchanging the two mounts (the old "/" which was the initramfs is moved to a sub-mount).

The minimal "/bin" and "/etc" and "/lib" that were unpacked from the initramfs *do* disappear during this process.

In other words, the process is approximately:

1. The kernel mounts an empty tmpfs at `/`.
2. The kernel unpacks the initramfs.cpio archive into the in-memory `/`, which contains some minimal files in /bin, /lib, etc.
3. The kernel runs `/init`, which is the "core" of the initramfs.
4. The initramfs /init script reads "root=" from the kernel command line (or uses some other method) and mounts the real root filesystem at `/newroot` or something similar. At this point, your files are at /newroot/lib, /newroot/home, and so on.
5. The initramfs optionally mounts other necessary things under /newroot, such as a tmpfs at "/newroot/run", or a NFS-based /usr as "/newroot/usr".
6. The initramfs /init turns `/newroot` into `/` using, I believe, one of two methods:

   - it deletes all files that were unpacked into the initramfs "/", then *moves* the "/newroot" mount onto "/" (overlaying the now-empty tmpfs which stays there forever) and uses chroot() to make it permanent – this is what's done by Arch Linux's initramfs using the switch_root tool;
   - or it calls pivot_root() to "swap" the initramfs / with /newroot, turning the latter into the new / and moving the initramfs to something like /run/initramfs which can then be unmounted – not sure if this method is still used.
7. Finally, now that "/" is the real root, /init (still running from memory) executes the real root filesystem's `/sbin/init`.

Often the initramfs /init is a simple shell script (though not always; it could even be a full copy of systemd). You can take a look at the [Arch mkinitcpio /init](https://gitlab.archlinux.org/archlinux/mkinitcpio/mkinitcpio/-/blob/master/init#L110-112). This internally uses the "overlay using mount(MS_MOVE)" method; see e.g. [switch_root](https://github.com/util-linux/util-linux/blob/master/sys-utils/switch_root.c#L178-L181) from util-linux.

Comment: Not sure about the delete part :-)

Comment: It really does delete the contents of the ramfs, as otherwise they would just continue occupying memory (sometimes a whole ~200MB of it) while being inaccessible. See [here](https://github.com/util-linux/util-linux/blob/master/sys-utils/switch_root.c#L198-L205), [here](https://github.com/mirror/busybox/blob/master/util-linux/switch_root.c#L238-L260), [here](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/main/src/shared/switch-root.c#L124), etc.

Comment: Woah, thanks. That looks kinda weird to me, almost like a crutch.

Comment: I suppose it would be cleaner to pivot_root, allowing the ramfs to be simply unmounted once it's no longer at "/", but... the initramfs /init process itself can't unmount the filesystem it's running from (thus requiring cooperation from the next-stage init), and the rootfs might not have a directory that could be used to place the old / (although that's less of a problem nowadays with /run being a thing as the directory could just be created there), which is _probably_ why the "empty and overmount" method is being used.

Comment: A note in the kernel suggests the rootfs cannot be `pivot_root`'d: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/fs/namespace.c#n3859. I.e. an initramfs must do the first bullet under 6 in your list. Rootfs cannot be unmounted, because the VFS mechanism is "naturally" nonempty ("same reason you can't kill the `init`": https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/filesystems/ramfs-rootfs-initramfs.rst). Rootfs is *always* attached to `/`, even if empty or mounted over. This ensures the VFS always works.

Comment: @HTNW It also ensures that no special semantics are required in the VFS layer for the ‘real’ root filesystem, which greatly simplifies the implementation in a number of ways.

Comment: Interesting, is pivot_root then just a leftover of the old initrd mechanism (which I'm not really familiar with)?